# Лишняя запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"...с сухим, точно припудренным(,) лицом" - нужна тут запятая или все-таки она лишняя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

От авторского смысла зависит.
Если "точно припудренным" явлеяется по мысли автора уточняющим для "сухим", то такое уточнение обособляется, запятая нужна. Если это однородные определения, то не нужна.
По мне - первое горазде вернее, я бы эту запятую оставил.